# what is the difference between on, in or at a meeting?

Tags: prepositions, prepositional-phrases

what is the difference between the following sentence:

1, He is in a meeting.

2, He is at a meeting.

3, He is on a meeting.

I have found that the difference between first 2 sentences is [in a meeting implies being on the same premises as the speaker, but at a meeting implies being on a different premises than the speaker..](https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/in-a-meeting-or-at-a-meeting.179968/)

But I did find any information about on a meeting or on the meeting on google, however, I found there are [380 records about on a meeting and 880 records about on the meeting on http://corpus.byu.edu/now/](http://corpus.byu.edu/now/), and although some of those records are not what I'm asking.

So, I want to know if we can use the preposition on in front meeting? And if so, what is the difference between the 3 sentences?

Comment: You should add example sentences that you found that illustrate your concern.

Answer (score 8):

You've rightly called out the differences between the first two statements:

> He is in a meeting

The above statement refers to the person attending a meeting in the same premises (i.e. on site).

On the other hand:

> He is at a meeting

Refers to the person attending a meeting at another premises (i.e. off-site).

Coming to your third statement:

> He is on a meeting

The above statement incorrect, and should not be use. The preposition "*on*" would only be used for calls, such as:

> He is on the phone

Although one often hears people mentioning "His is on a call", it is probably preferable to state it as "in a call" to reflect the fact that he is in a phone call. "On a call" tends to give an impression of a professional making a house call (e.g. a doctor visiting a patient, or a plumber at a home for repairs).

*Note: the above paragraph was edited based on @user3169's input. The original version said "on a call" was incorrect, while in reality it isn't that black-and-white.*

Upvoting your question for the research you've put into it.

Comment: Why is "on a call" incorrect?

Comment: "On a call" tends to imply being on a house call (e.g. a doctor visiting a patient) as opposed to using the phone. Take a look at this: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/16504/in-a-call-versus-on-a-call

Comment: I wasn't really arguing, but since both versions are commonly used you might add your explanation to your answer (rather than just saying it is wrong).

Comment: Very fair point. I have amended my answer to reflect that.

Comment: You are too quick to dismiss *on*; the idea that *on* suggests a house call is rather old-fashioned— such a case would more likely be expressed as being *out on a call*. Similarly, *on* can be used in reference to items on an agenda, and so my assistant might say I am *on a meeting*, *on lunch*, or *on training* if asked for.

Answer (score 2):

> He is in a meeting.

Implies the subject is meeting with others nearby in an enclosed space such as an office of conference room.

> He is at a meeting.

Implies the subject is meeting somewhere else where the details of the space are unknown such on a different floor or in a different building.

> He is on a meeting.

Implies the subject is participating in a video or conference call.